# Game Center automatically gives me all achievements

Tags: ios, game-center

I'm trying to test Game Center, and I've gotten as far as unlocking 2 achievements. I keep changing things, so I delete my game, reset my cache, gamecenter info (achievements/leaderboards) to test it from scratch. The problem is that when I reinstall the app, it just gives me all of the achievements.

Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: My guess is that the data is saved with apple and it checks through that and then gives you the achievement.

Comment: So the only way to really check is to make testing achievements?

Comment: I have not done much work with game center but my guess is apple stores the achievement data so if you re download the game it sends it that you already have the achievement and gives it to you.

Answer (score 0):

This C# method will reset (clear or delete) all achievements that a player has earned:

```
    public void resetAchievement()  // Reset Achievement -- reset achievement
    {
        earnedAchievementCache = null;

        GKAchievement.ResetAchivements ((error) => {{
            if(error == null)
                new UIAlertView ("Achievement reset", "Achievement reset successfully", null, "OK", null).Show ();
            else
                new UIAlertView ("Reset failed", "Reset failed because: " + error, null, "OK", null).Show ();
        });
    }
```

This method works well for me as I am testing my game now, and I am constantly defining, earning, and deleting achievements.

By the way, unless I am mistaken, I think that developers can only reset (or delete) player's achievements during the testing phase, and once the achievements have gone LIVE and the players have earned the achievements, perhaps iOS Game Center won't let developers delete those achievements.